# Woocommerce add to cart button not working when user not logged in

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Woocommerce add to cart button not working when user not logged in. but when a user logged in its works fine and also when I disable ajax add to cart(It reloads the page when adding the item) its works fine too.
`?wc-ajax=add_to_cart` call returns `302` error when this happens, but when a user is logged in it returns `200` successfully.

I disabled all the plugins and tried also but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. 
Then I found one of the tables on the database was missing.
You can check that by going to Woocommerce>Status and check if there are any missing tables. Mine was "wp_woocommerce_sessions" table.

Fix: Goto Tools tab on Status and Run the "Update database" tool and "Verify base database tables" tool. 
 My issue was resolved after that.